# Scala implicit conversion called twice

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to instantiate classes from Maps[String, Any], receiving through some json-rpc. 
So I end up with following problem:

```
val mpa:Map[String, Any] = Map("key"->0.0)

implicit def anyToInt(a:Any):Int = a.asInstanceOf[Double].toInt
```

When key exists all is OK.

```
val i:Int = mpa.getOrElse("key", 0.0)
i: Int = 0
```

But when key is missing ...:

```
scala> val i:Int = mpa.getOrElse("val", 0.0)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(Unknown Source)
at .anyToInt(<console>:13
```

Now, if we're add some verbosity as:

```
implicit def anyToInt(a:Any):Int = {
  println(a)
  val b = a.asInstanceOf[Double].toInt
  println("converted")
  b
}
```

We got:

```
val i:Int = mpa.getOrElse("val", 0.0)
0.0
converted
0
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
     .....
```

So i came to the conclusion that anyToInt is called twice. And the second time it received Int as Any.

Questions:

1. Why ?!
2. What should I do to avoid this ?

P.S.: Sorry if it's newbie question. I'm new in scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having hidden direct conversions and especially for `Any` as it is in your case is a very bad idea and you've discovered why. I'd advice you to simply convert your input map into `Map[String, Int]`. You don't need implicits here, but if you still want to go with implicits you should do it with wrapper approach:

```
implicit def anyExtender (x: Any) = new {
  def toInt = x match {
    case x: Double => x.toInt
  }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
mpa.getOrElse("val", 0.0).toInt
```

Since scala 2.10 the following implementation of implicit wrappers is preferred:

```
implicit class AnyExtender (x: Any) {
  def toInt = x match {
    case x: Double => x.toInt
  }
}
```

Also since your conversion function does not work on all subtypes of `Any` it is incorrect to extend `Any` with such a function, it would be correct to extend `Double` with such a function but it already has it. So in your scenario the only correct way of using your map would be simply as follows:

```
map.getOrElse("val", 0.0).asInstanceOf[Double].toInt
```

## Update

Conversion to `Map[String, Int]` will work for you, if you move the logic you wanted to place in implicits like so:

```
val resultMapOfStringToIntType = 
  inputMapOfStringToAnyType.mapValues {
    case x: Double => x.toInt
    case x: String => x.toInt
    case x: Timestamp => //...
    // and so on
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Works for me. 

P.S.: About convertion to Map[String, Int] - it won't work for me, as this map contains also String's, Timestamp's etc. 

P.P.S.: And yet - why in my case anyToInt called twice? :)

Comment: map.getOrElse("val", 0.0).asInstanceOf[Double].toInt
This where I start from :) Bad option, when you had approximatly 40 fields of different types.

Comment: On "PS", look at the update in answer. On "PPS", I think your implicit got called twice because `Int` as much as every other type in Scala does inherit from `Any`, so your implicit conversion has fallen into recursion by calling itself on `Int`s too.

Comment: Update perhaps close to what I want, with one "but" - fields of my object also can be Int, String, Timestamp. And on "PPS" it's not seems like recursion, because we see 0.0->"converted"->0->exception. In case of recursion we must see 0.0->0->exception. Anyway, thanks for your answers. Now I see two ways. First - as I did before - set all fields manualy. Second - make an Extender. There is third way, may be, make universal initializer, but it requires Reflection, which is absent in 2.9.1.